# splitting xml based on 3 tags

Tags: xml, perl, split

I have a  single xml file which contains multiple lines.. i want to split the xml based on GroupName,subGroupName,class

i have a perl code which will split based on GroupName. can you provide the command to split based on GroupName,subGroupName,class

```
while (my $line = <INPUT>){

    $line=~ m'<GroupName>([\W\w]*?)</GroupName>';
    
    my $groupid=$1;

    if (defined($groupid)){

        $groupid=~s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    
        my $output=$groupid.$env_name;
```

inputfile:

```
<GroupName>GROUP1</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB1</subGroupName><class>CLASS1</class>
<GroupName>GROUP1</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB1</subGroupName><class>CLASS1</class>
<GroupName>GROUP2</GroupName><subGroupName>VV</subGroupName><class>VV</class>
<GroupName>GROUP3</GroupName><subGroupName>VV</subGroupName><class>VV</class>
<GroupName>GROUP4</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB1</subGroupName><class>VV</class>
<GroupName>GROUP4</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB2</subGroupName><class>VV</class>
<GroupName>GROUP5</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB1</subGroupName><class>CLASS1</class>
<GroupName>GROUP5</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB2</subGroupName>
<GroupName>GROUP5</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB1</subGroupName><class>CLASS1</class>
<GroupName>GROUP5</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB2</subGroupName>
```

output:

File 1- GROUP1_SUB1_CLASS1.xml

`<GroupName>GROUP1</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB1</subGroupName><class>CLASS1</class> <GroupName>GROUP1</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB1</subGroupName><class>CLASS1</class>`

File 2- GROUP2_VV_VV.xml

`<GroupName>GROUP2</GroupName><subGroupName>VV</subGroupName><class>VV</class>`

File 3- GROUP3_VV_VV.xml

`<GroupName>GROUP3</GroupName><subGroupName>VV</subGroupName><class>VV</class>`

File 4- GROUP4_SUB1_VV.xml

`<GroupName>GROUP4</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB1</subGroupName><class>VV</class>`

File 5- GROUP4_SUB2_VV.xml

`<GroupName>GROUP4</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB2</subGroupName><class>VV</class>`

File 6- GROUP5_SUB1_CLASS1.xml

`<GroupName>GROUP5</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB1</subGroupName><class>CLASS1</class>`

`<GroupName>GROUP5</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB1</subGroupName><class>CLASS1</class>`

File 7- GROUP5_SUB2.xml

`<GroupName>GROUP5</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB2</subGroupName>`

`<GroupName>GROUP5</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB2</subGroupName>`

Comment: Use a XML parser instead of regex. Ex: `XML::LibXML` or `XML::Parser`

Comment: I cleaned up some markup, on the input file and code.  But your "code" is unfinished -- please edit the question to complete it.   I suggest to reformat the desired output (you can see what I did for the input)

Comment: The input file you show isn't a valid XML file; it is missing a root element. That is easily tacked on -- but is there anything else that's different than shown? Then, what is shown isn't much of an XML since all these "nodes" just follow each other, there is no nested structure.  Is that indeed what you have?

Answer (score 1):

As always, process XML with libraries, and [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) is excellent.

However, the shown input isn't a meaningful XML file. Never mind the missing root element, the real problem is that it is a set of disjoint nodes, without a typical nested XML structure<sup>†</sup> so I am not sure how to leverage a parser for this document.

Until that's fixed or clarified ... let me imagine that it ain't XML but just any old file with somewhat regular patterns.  Here's a way to process it as needed

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump qw(dd);  # or use core Data::Dumper

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 input-file\n";

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!"; 

my %res;

my $re_grp = qr{<GroupName>([^<]+)</GroupName>};
my $re_sub = qr{<subGroupName>([^<]+)</subGroupName>};
my $re_cls = qr{<class>([^<]+)</class>};

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp; 
    if ( my ($grp, $sub, $cls) = m{$re_grp $re_sub $re_cls}x ) { 
        #say "$grp -- $sub -- $cls";
        my $key_name = join '_', $grp, $sub, $cls;
        push @{$res{$key_name}}, $_; 
    }   
}
close $fh;    
dd \%res;

# Save them to files
for my $k (sort keys %res) { 
    my $fout = "$k.xml";
    open my $fh, '>', $fout or do {
        warn "Can't open $fout: $!";
        next;
    };
    say $fh $_ for @{$res{$k}};
}
```

This writes files as asked, like `GROUP1_SUB1_CLASS1.xml` file:

```
<GroupName>GROUP1</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB1</subGroupName><class>CLASS1</class>
<GroupName>GROUP1</GroupName><subGroupName>SUB1</subGroupName><class>CLASS1</class>
```

(etc)  But, again, these things don't have a hierarchical structure typical of XML, and what XML is meant for.  Please clarify if you actually need something else.

---

<sup>†</sup> `subGroupName` *is not* a descendant node of `GroupName` but only follows it, etc.

Comment: The OP wants to do a transformation to create the nested structure, as far as I can see. That's a perfectly legitimate thing to want to do.

Comment: @MichaelKay  "_The OP wants to do a transformation to create the nested structure_"  -- well, that's not what they are showing.  They show merely splitting it up (and they say so, in the title and text), and into an equally unstructured sets of tags in each output file.  Wanting to create an actual XML would be reasonable, yes.  But where do you see that they want that?

Comment: @MichaelKay Then, I asked about it, below the question.  Hopefully they clarify...

Comment: Yes, there's a difference between what they need to do and what they say they want to do. I've read between the lines and assume they want to create structure from their current mess, but I agree, they haven't got as far as realising what that entails.

Comment: @MichaelKay OK, that _would_ make sense (but the shown desired output doesn't betray such intentions).  Hopefully they come back and talk.

Comment: Well by splitting it into separate files they're at least adding a llitle bit of structure, hopefully we can show them how to add a lot more.

Comment: @MichaelKay "_...hopefully we can show them how to add a lot more_"  That's a good point.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple enough task in XSLT 3.0, despite the lack of structure in the input. Assuming the existence of a wrapper element, first add wrappers around each GROUP and its immediate siblings:

```
<xsl:variable name="groups" as="element(group)*">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="/*/*" group-starting-with="GroupName">
    <group><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
  </xsl;for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>
```

and now group these by common values, sending each group to a different output XML file:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$groups"
  group-by="GroupName, subGroupName, class" composite="yes">
  <xsl:result-document href="{GroupName}_{subGroupName}_{class}">
     <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

That will produce something close to what you asked for, though I'd suggest revising it so the output files are well-formed XML (with an outer wrapper element).

Don't attempt this using Perl and regular expressions: it's the wrong tool for the job.